# How to make app design for more different builds?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have built an app at works which can be offered to many different customers so my job is to make the modern app design for many builds.
Lets say we sell one copy of it to youtube and it has to have red theme and then we sell one to facebook and it has to have blue theme. How is this possible? Can you give me some guidance please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a video guiding you through what you asked: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWnkWHF2lFQ

Answer (score 3):

You can start by reading this guide on [build variant configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants). **Product flavors** is what you are looking for.

In your example you would have two product flavors - youtube and facebook.
The style, resource files and custom code then would be stored in directories corresponding to the flavor name and the shared code and resources would be stored int the main directory.

When building the app you specify witch flavor to use, and the specified flavor directory gets merged with the main app code and resources.